# Is there anything I can do if my google apps emails are being bounced?

Tags: email, gmail, google-workspace

I have an email address with google apps that is oscar@oscarfoley.com
If I send emails **to** it, they don't arrive and, sometimes, I receive this bounce email:

> Subject: [Postmaster] Email Delivery Warning
>
> This message is a warning that an email you are trying to send has not
>   yet been delivered. You do not have to do anything yet as the email is
>   still queued for delivery.
>
> An email you addressed to email address :
>   -- oscar@oscarfoley.com
>
> has not yet been delivered. The problem appears to be :
>   -- Recipient server unavailable or busy
>
> Additional information follows :
>   -- Connection timed out
>
> This condition occurred after 6 attempt(s) to deliver over a period of
>   1 hour(s).
>
> You will receive a rejection notice after a maximum of 4 days if the
>   email cannot be delivered. If you sent the email to multiple
>   recipients you will receive one of these messages for each one which
>   is still undelivered, otherwise they have been sent.

I think the problems is on Google mail server, so I should **wait**... but this have been happening for more than 5 days...

**Is there anything I could do?**

Comment: This indicates a problem at google, not you. If it persists, contact google to inquire, but there won't be anything that _you_ can do.

Comment: If you're running the mail server for that host check your mail server logs. Maybe you are actively rejecting google from delivering mail to you (though the message should be different in that case).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You has no MX and SPF at oscarfoley.com DNS

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;oscarfoley.com.                        IN      MX

Take a look with your hosting company or where you have your DNS servers...

You need to setup Google Suite DNS settings.

Take a look at https://support.google.com/a/answer/174125

Comment: I have my DNS in onlinenic. It was working fine until 5 days ago...Will check now

Comment: Your DNS servers are now at: 

;; ANSWER SECTION:
oscarfoley.com.         300     IN      NS      ns11025.ztomy.com.
oscarfoley.com.         300     IN      NS      ns21025.ztomy.com.

Contact your DNS service provider to correct your DNS settings to Google Suite.

Comment: Maybe my domain expired... :-(

Comment: It's not expired.

Registry Expiry Date: 2019-03-09T21:04:10Z

Comment: Someone registered it :-(

Comment: It was parked so I managed to renew it :-)